# Cocos2d: Using single timer/scheduler for multiple sprites

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nstimer, box2d-iphone

I want to know if is it possible to use single timer or scheduler method for multiple sprites ? Like I am now working on a game and there could be any number of sprites and i want to perform some actions on all of those sprites, So do I have to use as many timers or schedulers as sprites ? Or How can the job be done using only a single timer or scheduler ? 
What if I schedule a method and use it for, Say 10 sprites ? Will it affect the performance..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common for most games. Normally you'd use a list of objects that are similar to make different operations. Particle systems work like this, with a single object they update all the sprites positions.
In my game though, I have a lot of objects and each of them has their own update function, even if they're the same type.

```
for (GameObject* object in objects)
    [object update:dt];
```

I guess its more of a performance thing that should be optimized once you run into the problem, or if you know that you'll be doing heavy processing. Something like this could be on the update function, would involve less function calls, and would probably be more efficient, but I dont think its really worth it, as the thing id try to optimize first would probably be on the drawing side instead of the logic side (like spritebatch or particle systems do).

```
for (CCSprite* sprite in sprite)
{
    sprite.x = someVariable;
}
```